# Google Apps Script search and replace URL truncates 1 character in rendered link

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm using the code below to search for URLs in a Google Doc and turn them into active links. It works beautifully, *except* that the link cuts off the last character of the URL (e.g. "https://link.com/123" gets linked as "https://link.com/12").

```
function updateLinks() {
  var linkRegex = "https?:\/\/[^\\s]*";

  //Open active doc
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  //Find URLs
  var link = body.findText(linkRegex);

  //Loop through the body finding texts matching the search pattern
  while (link != null) {
    // Get the link as an object
    var linkElement = link.getElement().asText();
    // Get the positions of start and end
    var start = link.getStartOffset();
    var end = link.getEndOffsetInclusive();
    //slice only the link out of it
    var correctLink = linkElement.getText().slice(start, end);

    // Format link
    linkElement.setLinkUrl(start, end, correctLink);
    // Find next
    link = body.findText(linkRegex, link);
  }
}
```

I'm sure this is simple, but I'm a complete novice and would appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that the reason of your issue is due to `slice(start, end)` of `linkElement.getText().slice(start, end)`. In this case, it is required to be `slice(start, end + 1)`. So, please modify it as follows and test it again.

#### From:

```
var correctLink = linkElement.getText().slice(start, end);
```

#### To:

```
var correctLink = linkElement.getText().slice(start, end + 1);
```

Or, when you want to use `linkRegex`, how about the following modification?

```
var correctLink = linkElement.getText().match(new RegExp(linkRegex))[0];
```

#### Note:

- As additional information, when the multiple URLs are included in a paragraph, I think that the following modification might be useful. Of course, in this modification, even when a single URL is included in a paragraph, the script works.

  - From

    ```
      var start = link.getStartOffset();
      var end = link.getEndOffsetInclusive();
      //slice only the link out of it
      var correctLink = linkElement.getText().slice(start, end);

      // Format link
      linkElement.setLinkUrl(start, end, correctLink);
    ```
  - To

    ```
      var text = linkElement.getText();
      var correctLinks = [...text.matchAll(new RegExp(linkRegex, "g"))];
      correctLinks.forEach(obj => linkElement.setLinkUrl(obj.index, obj.index + obj[0].length - 1, obj[0]));
    ```

#### Reference:

- [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Comment: Your solution to add +1 after "end" worked perfectly. Simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### Your code is working for me

What do your original files look like?

```
function updateLinks() {
  var linkRegex = "https?:\/\/[^\\s]*";
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var link = body.findText(linkRegex);
  while (link != null) {
    var linkElement = link.getElement().asText();
    var start = link.getStartOffset();
    var end = link.getEndOffsetInclusive();
    var correctLink = linkElement.getText().slice(start, end);
    linkElement.setLinkUrl(start, end, correctLink);
    link = body.findText(linkRegex, link);
  }
}
```